# parsing url with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url in this form http://www.example.com/data/45. How do I get the last element (45 in this example) using jQuery or JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very quick plain JavaScript method, assuming it's the URL of the current page (in `window.location.href`)

```
var urlNum = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
```

`.split('/')` obviously chops the URL up into an array, based on divisions by `/`. Since you only need the last part, it is probably the easiest method.

`.pop()` removes the last element from the array returned by `.split()` and returns it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = 'http://www.example.com/data/45'.split('/').pop(); //num now == '45'
```

Answer (score 0):

My rendition :)

```
var url         = 'http://www.example.com/data/45';
var lastSegment = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```